# Installing ubuntu on an HP chromebook

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, chromebook

I have a chrome book. hp chromebook 14.
I want to install ubuntu on it.
No dual booting. just simple ubuntu.
is there a way?

Comment: I think the only way to install Ubuntu on a Chromebook is to keep Chrome OS, since Crouton is required.

Comment: I tried. couldnt find it. thats why im here.
I guess I have to edit the bios somehow

Comment: @Zacharee1 Most software doesnt work for some reason. tried to use Qt, doesnt even open.

Comment: @tomkis that doesn't mean installing Ubuntu by itself will fix those problems. This sounds a lot like an XY Problem. Ask about your problem, not about a solution you're trying.

Comment: What I do before installing Ubuntu is check the hardware compatibility list found on Ubuntu.com. If its there it works, if not then it may or may not work. I looked for your HP Chromebook and did not see it on the list.

Comment: There are 3 different models, please specify which one you have http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices xicronic's answer is mostly correct, but installation methods can differ from model to model and GalliumOS is not an offical flavor, thus questions regarding it should be asked somewhere else e.g. Unix & Linux SE.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking a look at [GalliumOS](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Hardware_Compatibility). It's based on Xubuntu 16.04 but with certain modifications to run better on Chromebooks, such as special kernel patches for audio support. Linked above is their hardware compatibility chart detailing which Chromebooks are compatible with GalliumOS, and what steps are needed to install it.